# How can I offset a texture in Geometry Node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

It is important that the texture is offseted and not just the geometry in general. I want the texture to "float" through the geometry. Like this.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding some vector to `Position` let you move the noise.

[image]